# DropDown Lists issue ZURB foundation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

Clicking on the button does not create a dropdown list as I believe it should. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here or why it might not be working?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<meta charset="" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scaler=1.0" />
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <a href="#" class="button dropdown" data-dropdown="drop1">dropdown</a>
    </div>
</div>
    <ul class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content id="drop1">
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
    </ul>


<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't have **jquery** loaded, also, something is wrong with your css/js files, double check your **paths**.

```html
    <!doctype html>
<head>
    <html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <meta charset="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scaler=1.0" />

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.2/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
    <body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
        <a href="#" class="button" data-dropdown="drop">Link Dropdown &raquo;</a>
    <ul id="drop" class="tiny f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
      <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
    </ul>
          </div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.2/js/foundation.js"></script>
      <script>
      $(document).foundation();
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The head tag is also missing. It will be nice to add it.

Comment: I looked at the links and it does appear they are not working, I used your script links to a site and everything started working fine. The thing is my paths are correct and i am using similar paths (as well as receiving an error) for linking images but the images appear correctly where as linked scripts do not work.